# How do you find the asymptotic distribution of a function of the sample mean?

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, mean, function

There are a number of questions on this site that ask for the asymptotic distribution or moments of some function of the sample mean for IID data (see e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466596/), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/377707/), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123264/), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314021/) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60988/)).  All these questions are for specific functions and distributions, but they all seem to employ the same general method.  So, is there is any *general result* that can be applied for an arbitrary function of the sample mean for IID data from an arbitrary distribution?

Suppose you have some IID data $X_1,X_2,X_3,... \sim \text{IID Dist}$ from a fixed distribution (which doesn't have to be the normal distribution) and you form the sample mean $\bar{X}_n$ from the first $n$ data points.  Suppose you also have some arbitrary function $g$.  Is there any general form for the asymptotic distribution of $g(\bar{X}_n)$?

Answer (score 4):

The question is a little bit too general in its present form to get a useful result.  Nevertheless, with some slight restrictions we can get a useful general form for the asymptotic distribution using the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method).  To do this, let's assume that the underlying distribution for the data has a finite mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$.  This allows us to apply the central limit theorem to get the asymptotic distribution $\bar{X}_n \sim \text{N}(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$, which means that $\bar{X}_n \rightarrow \mu$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Since the sample mean gets closer and closer to the true mean in the limit, we can see that the asymptotic distribution of $g(\bar{X}_n)$ will be fully determined by the local behaviour of the function $g$ in a neighbourhood of the point $\mu$.

To proceed further, let's make some mild assumptions about this local behaviour.  Specifically, we will reduce the scope of the allowable functions by assuming that $g$ is an analytic function at $\mu$ (i.e., the function $g$ is infinitely differentiable at this point and it is representable by its Taylor series representation at this point).  Thus, for all points $x$ in a neighbourhood of $\mu$ we can write the function $g$ as:

$$g(x) = g(\mu) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{g^{(k)}(\mu)}{k!} \cdot (x-\mu)^k.$$

The asymptotic distribution depends on which derivatives of the function are zero at the point $\mu$.  Without loss of generality, let $K = \min \{ k = 1,2,3,... | g^{(k)}(\mu) \neq 0 \}$ denote the order of the first non-zero derivative of the function at the mean of the random variable under analysis, which means we have $g^{(1)}(\mu) = \cdots = g^{(K-1)}(\mu) = 0$.  To facilitate our analysis we also define the standardised sample mean $Z_n \equiv \sqrt{n} (\bar{X}_n-\mu)/\sigma$.  We can now write the Taylor expansion of interest as:

$$\begin{aligned}
g(\bar{X}_n) 
&= g(\mu) + \sum_{k=K}^\infty \frac{g^{(k)}(\mu)}{k!} \cdot (\bar{X}_n-\mu)^k \\[6pt]
&= g(\mu) + \sum_{k=K}^\infty \frac{g^{(k)}(\mu)}{k!} \cdot \sigma^k \cdot \frac{Z_n^k}{n^{k/2}}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

As we take $n \rightarrow \infty$ we can apply the [classical central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) to get the asymptotic distribution $Z_n \sim \text{N}(0,1)$, and so the higher order terms in this expansion will converge to zero much more rapidly than the term of order $K$.  The asymptotic distribution of our function at the sample mean will be determined by the $K$th term of the Taylor series:

$$\begin{aligned}
g(\bar{X}_n) 
&\sim g(\mu) + \frac{g^{(K)}(\mu)}{K!} \cdot \sigma^K \cdot \frac{Z_n^K}{n^{K/2}}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

We can see from this result that the asymptotic distribution is heavily dependent on the order value $K$.  If $K=1$ then the asymptotic distribution will be a normal distribution, if $K=2$ then the asymptotic distribution will be a scaled chi-squared distribution, if $K=3$ then the asymptotic distribution is for the scaled version of the cube of a normal random variable (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412249/) for discussion), and so on.